# How to get StatusCode from request in PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, logging, invoke-webrequest

I need to get success and/or error status code from a request using power shell. And i'm always getting a blank status.

I have tried with Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod.
I have sucess on the call but can't find a way of getting the status code.

Here how is currently written:

```
$resource = "some url"
$Logfile = "C:/path/log.log"

function LogWrite
{
    Param([string]$logstring)

    Add-content $logfile -value $logstring
}

Try
{
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $resource 
    Write-Output("Success.")
    LogWrite $Date
    LogWrite SuccessOnCall
    LogWrite  $Response.StatusCode
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Output($ErrorMessage)
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception
    Write-Output($FailedItem)
    LogWrite $Date
    LogWrite ErrorOnCall
    LogWrite $ErrorMessage
    Break
}
```

I have also tried:

```
LogWrite "StatusCode:" $Response.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
```

I used this question (and other links) : [Invoke-Restmethod: how do I get the return code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622526/invoke-restmethod-how-do-i-get-the-return-code)

Trying to solve this, my log does write "SuccessOnCall" but the StatusCode is blank.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't replicate this using www.google.com as the URL. Using a get succeeds and a post fails but the status code is written correctly to the log in both cases.
`SuccessOnCall
200

ErrorOnCall
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.`

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `Write-Output(arg1, ...)`, use `Write-Output arg1  ...` - PowerShell cmdlets and functions are invoked like _shell commands_ , not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_). Better yet, instead of calling `Write-Output`, use [_implicit_ output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375).

Comment: You'll want to refer to `$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__` inside the `catch` block

Answer (score 17):

did you try pipe'ing with select-object ?

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri apiEndpoint -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object StatusCode
```

output

```
StatusCode
 ----------
   200
```

or just to get status code

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri apiEndpoint -UseBasicParsing | Select-Object -Expand StatusCode
```

output

```
200
```

---

to handle unsuccessful cases,
on PowerShell v#7 + include `-SkipHttpErrorCheck` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7)
or
you may need to make use of [`$Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-error?view=powershell-7#example-3--send-a-collection-of-errors-to-receive-detailed-messages) array to get most recent error and access properties accordingly.

Comment: How can I parse output if there is an error? For example, If code is 200, all okay, i get "200" as output. But if 404, I get several error strings even with "Select-Object -Expand StatusCode" :)

Comment: open to exploration  :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2#example-7-catch-non-success-messages-from-invoke-webrequest

Answer (score 3):

The below example shows how to get the response Status code (even if the response status code was not 200). We can get the exception information in the catch block using the $_ variable ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-exceptions?view=powershell-7.4#trycatch )

```
$Url = "https://some.web.page.net"
try
    {  
    $request = Invoke-WebRequest $Url -UseBasicParsing -UseDefaultCredentials       
    [int]$StatusCode = $request.StatusCode
    }
catch 
    {
    [int]$StatusCode = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    }
$StatusCode
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -Uri 'google.com' | select-object StatusCode
```

Comment: does this rly work? I cannot get it to run