# How can i get around the Invoke-RestMethod error: unexpected error on send, even after setting the TLS?

Tags: powershell

Here is my current script-Running Powershell version 5.1.14393.6343

```
clear-host
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Ssl3

$pass = & \\special\encrypted\hashkey\script\ThatConvertsHashToPassword.exe 909cb74a7e0ac4cd3f57357a07034f20ac52c08e8d062316 d
$username = ‘UserThatlogsinfromAnywhere’
$Securepassword =ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force 
$WinrxCredential = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $Securepassword
$verifyquery = “https://11.111.111.111:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query?query=SELECT Caption,SysName,Unmanaged,NodeID,URI FROM Orion.Nodes WHERE Nodes.SysName='NameOfSystem'”
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $verifyquery -Credential $WinrxCredential -ContentType "application/json"
$res = $results | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Results
write-host $res
```

This returns Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

However, if i change the port to 443 instead of 17778, instead it fails to return the Results of ExpandProperty. If i remove that line and instead just return the result of the Invoke-RestMethod, i get a whole bunch of HTML/Json formatted text which is most definitely not the expected output. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think the site is using OAUTH2.  OAUTH2 is a two step authentication where first step is to get a token/cookie and second step is to send the query.  The formatted text that is being returned is the first step with the token.   If TLS was failing you would not get a response.  TLS is performed before the HTTP request is sent to establish an encrypted connection.  When TLs fails the request is never sent and you never get a response.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` automatically follows redirects, try using `Invoke-WebRequest` instead which will return the full response including headers and status code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622526/invoke-restmethod-how-do-i-get-the-return-code

Comment: Is there enough data provided here to write an invoke-web request?

Comment: it turns out it was actually a firewall issue. this was confirmed by the networking team and could see the block occurring each time

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, if the firewall is closed to that connection no matter what you try it should block you. Our networking team is opening that connection on the ports needed for the connection to that server from the server i'm executing from.