For which status codes is Invoke-RestMethod throwing exceptions?
I'm building a PowerShell script and I want to master my fallback strategy using Invoke-RestMethod according to returned HTTP Status Codes.
I'm assuming that Invoke-RestMethod throws for any non 2XX status codes, but I can't find any explicit information about this in the documentation.
Can anyone confirm my thoughts?

See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613572/error-handling-for-invoke-restmethod-powershell

Side note: You can use https://httpstat.us/ to test for various return codes to see what it does or how it behaves.
